# Firebase Joins with multiple node objects

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having an issue with trying to structure my data in Firebase as well as then retrieve it, in order to meet this use case:

I have 'Users' and I have 'Groups'

```
{
Users:
    LpWgezRkC6EWS0sjXEWxhFl2: {
        userName: 'John Doe'
        etc...
    }
},
Groups: 
     12345: {
          PropertiesID: 78765,                     
          GroupName: 'MyPool',
          GroupOwner: 'LpWgezRkC6EWS0sjXEWxhFl2' 
          GroupPassword: 'jkhdfjkhfdkjhdfkjhfsae4euhh4FDDC'
          etc...
     }
}
```

Any user can join any Group.

I store this pairing(relationship) of users in groups in the "UserInGroups" node.

```
{
    UsersInGroups: {
        DUmwewIfzAbfWZN4NjS8mhX82: {  <- UserId
           12345: true                <- GroupId
        },
        LpWgezRkC6EWS0sjXEWxhFl2: {    
           12345: true                
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, each group has a 'Properties' nodes that controls specifics/behavior for the group.

```
{
  Properties:
     78765: {
          PropertyName: 'Custom',
          dateCreated:  '20170601',
          etc...
     },
     76421: {
          PropertyName: 'Admin',
          dateCreated:  '20170602',
          etc...
     }
}
```

With that all said, my app has a Dashboard view, where it displays all the group/properties information in a UICollectionView. It should display information such as:

- the GroupName
- the GroupOwner
- based on the PropertiesID in the 'Groups' node

  - PropertiesName
  - Properties creationDate

How would I go about "joining the nodes" so that I'm able to retrieve the Group information along with the Properties information;

based on if the User that's logged into the app is part of the Group (thus has an entry in the UsersInGroups node)?!

> UPDATE

Follow-up question in regards to the data structure...

Is it acceptable to do three (3) joins to get all the information I am looking to display in the UIColloection View.

Something like this:

```
let ref = firebase.database().ref("UsersInGroups")
ref.child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

    let groupsRef = firebase.database().ref("Groups")
    groupsRef.child(snapshot.key).observe(.value, with: { snap in

        let propertiesRef = firebase.database().ref("Properties")
        ref.child(snap.key).queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.value, with: { gamesnapshot in

              //Get all the info from firebase

        })
    })
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

In all the places you download "Groups" node, do you need that specific group's properties? If you do, you could make a new node inside "Groups" calling it properties, and list all the properties there.

Comment: I Was thinking i can duplicate the info, but I'm trying to see if three joins would be acceptable in practice as this does provide more flexibility while not worrying about data outta sync

Comment: I think this is an acceptable way to do this since the data structure you currently have is flattened. However, that comes with a cost of separate calls, but your data will be efficiently downloaded.